# VS2013 build fails if I output "ERROR" in the post build step - I think

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

This is a bit of an odd one, and I tried to Google it but didn't have much luck.  Also, I apologize for the long lead-in... but I think it's all info necessary to understand what's happening?

I'm working in C++, using Visual Studio 2013, and I have my own unit test implementation.  The test project is part of the solution, and there is a post build event which runs them (using the executable which was just built), and if that even returns non-0 then the build fails (as it should).

I also have my own macro-based output system which uses OutputDebugString to print to the output window in the development environment, so I can use statements like these:

```
AI_ERROR("Some ERROR message with C-style %s", "arguments");
AI_WARN("Some ERROR message with C-style %s", "arguments");
AI_LOG("Some ERROR message with C-style %s", "arguments");
AI_ERROR_CONFIG("Some ERROR message with C-style %s", "arguments");
AI_WARN_CONFIG("Some ERROR message with C-style %s", "arguments");
AI_LOG_CONFIG("Some ERROR message with C-style %s", "arguments");
```

Which will result in this output when I run the executable directly:

```
(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp:87 ERROR: Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp:88 WARNING: Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp:89 LOG: Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp:90 ERROR (CONFIGURATION): Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp:91 WARNING (CONFIGURATION): Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp:92 LOG (CONFIGURATION): Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
```

That all works - so far so good.

Here's where it gets a little weird.  If I run the executable for the tests directly, then it runs, and it prints the messages I showed above, and it returns 0 - which is expected, since I never wrote any code to do anything different.  However, when I compile and the tests are run as a post build event, it returns -1.  If I comment out the two error messages (the AI_ERROR and the AI_ERROR_CONFIG) then it returns 0, even though the output string still has the word "ERROR" in it.  This is actually the behavior I want - but this is a multi-compiler project, and I want to make sure that execution is consistent, so I want to make sure that I'm the one making it happen, not just the dev environment doing it for me.

Another thing that I notice is that in the output that I get when I compile, the words "error" and "warning" are lower case, but "log" is not - and they are not lowercase in the original code.  Here's what that output looks like:

```
1>(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp : 87 error : Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
1>(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp : 88 warning : Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
1>  (0.0000) tesaitest.cpp:89 LOG: Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
1>(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp : 90 error (CONFIGURATION): Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
1>(0.0000) tesaitest.cpp : 91 warning (CONFIGURATION): Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
1>  (0.0000) tesaitest.cpp:92 LOG (CONFIGURATION): Some ERROR message with C-style arguments
```

That part of the string is passed into the print function as an enum (either Error or ConfigError), but then I use vsnprintf_s to compile the whole message into a single char buffer before I pass it into OutputDebugString.

Of course, for added fun, because this only happens during compile, and not when I run the executable directly, I can't catch it in the debugger.

So... does anybody understand how/why MS is determining that these are errors and changing the return value?  Is there a setting where I can turn that off?  As I said, since this is a multi-compiler project, and also because I might want to be able to have cases where error messages don't actually represent failed tests (i.e. I want to test that error messages to get generated on bad input) I'd rather that I had full control over the return value...

Comment: I do not know about the returned value. Regarding the uppercase problem, check your add-ons. I am using an output colorized that detects the words "error" and "warning" and changes the color of the whole line. It does not check the syntax of the line: is only looking for error/warning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Visual Assist is my only addon.  Though that sounds like a nice one - somewhere way down on my "nuts to have" list is trying to colorize the output. :)